# Insert .xml file from my local machine into a single column of a SQL table

Tags: sql, xml, bulkinsert

I have a XML file in my local machine. I want to insert that file as *.xml* file into a single column of a SQL table.
I tried searching internet and don't find any proper answer. I got some answers which explains how to insert the records as a single row but I don't want to split the record and I just want to insert that file as *.xml*.

Screenshot:

[image]

the above record has been achieved my making calls through IVR but I want to read the file from local machine.

XML file:

```
<IVRDATA>
  <IVR>
    <CALLID>84CAB60BABB711E4BDB9C7154A250D84</CALLID>
    <ICM_CALLID>00-00-00</ICM_CALLID>
    <SESSIONID>10.195.188.78.1423062943712.293.HFS_DCSS_CVP</SESSIONID>
    <APP_ID>3</APP_ID>
    <APP_TYPE>DCSS</APP_TYPE>
    <VXMLSERVER>10.195.188.78</VXMLSERVER>
    <DNIS>8523</DNIS>
    <CLI>914461084538</CLI>
    <CALL_STARTDATETIME>04/02/2015 09:15:43</CALL_STARTDATETIME>
    <CALL_ENDDATETIME>04/02/2015 09:16:23</CALL_ENDDATETIME>
    <LANGCODE>en-us</LANGCODE>
    <SKILLNAME>HFS.DCSS.CSCC.en-us.SG</SKILLNAME>
    <AGENT_TRANSFER>N</AGENT_TRANSFER>
    <ENDTYPE>CD</ENDTYPE>
    <DISPOSITION>CD</DISPOSITION>
    <HOW_CALL_ENDED>HANGUP</HOW_CALL_ENDED>
    <CALL_END_REASON>NORMAL</CALL_END_REASON>
    <CALLER_INPUT>E</CALLER_INPUT>
    <FROM_EXT_VXML0>HFS.DCSS.CSCC.en-us.SG</FROM_EXT_VXML0>
    <FROM_EXT_VXML1>en-us</FROM_EXT_VXML1>
    <FROM_EXT_VXML2 />
    <FROM_EXT_VXML3 />
    <RTR_CL_KEY>00</RTR_CL_KEY>
    <RTR_SEQ_NUM>00</RTR_SEQ_NUM>
    <RTR_CL_KEY_DAY>00</RTR_CL_KEY_DAY>
    <RES1 />
    <RES2 />
    <RES3 />
    <RES4 />
    <RES5 />
    <RES6 />
    <RES7 />
    <RES8 />
    <RES9 />
    <RES10 />
  </IVR>
  <MENUDETAIL>
    <MENU>
      <MENUID>M1001</MENUID>
      <MENU_STARTTIME>04/02/2015 09:15:43</MENU_STARTTIME>
      <MENU_ENDTIME>04/02/2015 09:15:47</MENU_ENDTIME>
      <MENUOPTION>1</MENUOPTION>
      <MENUMODE>dtmf</MENUMODE>
      <MNURES1>NA</MNURES1>
      <MNURES2>NA</MNURES2>
    </MENU>
    <MENU>
      <MENUID>M1002</MENUID>
      <MENU_STARTTIME>04/02/2015 09:15:47</MENU_STARTTIME>
      <MENU_ENDTIME>04/02/2015 09:15:48</MENU_ENDTIME>
      <MENUOPTION>1</MENUOPTION>
      <MENUMODE>dtmf</MENUMODE>
      <MNURES1>NA</MNURES1>
      <MNURES2>NA</MNURES2>
    </MENU>
    <MENU>
      <MENUID>M1054</MENUID>
      <MENU_STARTTIME>04/02/2015 09:15:48</MENU_STARTTIME>
      <MENU_ENDTIME>04/02/2015 09:15:48</MENU_ENDTIME>
      <MENUOPTION>1</MENUOPTION>
      <MENUMODE>dtmf</MENUMODE>
      <MNURES1>NA</MNURES1>
      <MNURES2>NA</MNURES2>
    </MENU>
    <MENU>
      <MENUID>M1038</MENUID>
      <MENU_STARTTIME>04/02/2015 09:15:48</MENU_STARTTIME>
      <MENU_ENDTIME>04/02/2015 09:15:51</MENU_ENDTIME>
      <MENUOPTION>NA</MENUOPTION>
      <MENUMODE />
      <MNURES1>NA</MNURES1>
      <MNURES2>NA</MNURES2>
    </MENU>
    <MENU>
      <MENUID>D1003</MENUID>
      <MENU_STARTTIME>04/02/2015 09:15:51</MENU_STARTTIME>
      <MENU_ENDTIME>04/02/2015 09:15:59</MENU_ENDTIME>
      <MENUOPTION>198004947</MENUOPTION>
      <MENUMODE>dtmf</MENUMODE>
      <MNURES1>NA</MNURES1>
      <MNURES2>NA</MNURES2>
    </MENU>
    <MENU>
      <MENUID>M1039</MENUID>
      <MENU_STARTTIME>04/02/2015 09:15:59</MENU_STARTTIME>
      <MENU_ENDTIME>04/02/2015 09:16:03</MENU_ENDTIME>
      <MENUOPTION>1</MENUOPTION>
      <MENUMODE>dtmf</MENUMODE>
      <MNURES1>NA</MNURES1>
      <MNURES2>NA</MNURES2>
    </MENU>
    <MENU>
      <MENUID>D1004</MENUID>
      <MENU_STARTTIME>04/02/2015 09:16:03</MENU_STARTTIME>
      <MENU_ENDTIME>04/02/2015 09:16:15</MENU_ENDTIME>
      <MENUOPTION>359909410</MENUOPTION>
      <MENUMODE>dtmf</MENUMODE>
      <MNURES1>NA</MNURES1>
      <MNURES2>NA</MNURES2>
    </MENU>
    <MENU>
      <MENUID>M1041</MENUID>
      <MENU_STARTTIME>04/02/2015 09:16:15</MENU_STARTTIME>
      <MENU_ENDTIME>04/02/2015 09:16:17</MENU_ENDTIME>
      <MENUOPTION>1</MENUOPTION>
      <MENUMODE>dtmf</MENUMODE>
      <MNURES1>NA</MNURES1>
      <MNURES2>NA</MNURES2>
    </MENU>
  </MENUDETAIL>
  <EVENTDETAIL>
    <EVENT>
      <EVENTID>DC001</EVENTID>
      <EVENT_TIME>04/02/2015 09:15:47</EVENT_TIME>
      <EVNRES1 />
      <EVNRES2 />
    </EVENT>
  </EVENTDETAIL>
</IVRDATA>
```